# Find the adjacent neighbors of two-dimensional vector with respect to boundaries/limit of the vector

Tags: c++

I've created a two-dimensional vector of strings in C++ and it currently takes a "map" of different characters (e.g. R, I, -, etc) to represent different "zones" on the map. The program needs to be able to detect if the map has certain characters and if it does, it needs to check all the adjacent spots around it. Below is an example of a map that can be used. Note that the size of the vector is not static and can change depending on the map selected and it's size during the start of the program.

```
 , ,T,#,T,T,T,
I,I,I,-,C,C,T,
I,I,I,-,C,C,T,P
I,I,I,-,C,C,T,
-,-,-,-,-,-,#,-
 , ,-,R,R,R,T,
 , ,-,R,R,R, ,
 , ,-,R,R,R, ,
```

Let's say, for instance, I'm detecting if the map has character 'R' inside it. I've found an instance of 'R' at coordinate (5,3) and now I need to check all adjacent spots around it with respect to the boundaries of the vector; if the coordinate the program is currently at is a corner (e.g. 0,0) then it only has to check 3 adjacent spots whereas a coordinate of (5,3) has 8 adjacent spots to check.

I want to write a loop that automatically detects the boundaries of the vector so that when the program is checking the adjacent spots, it doesn't try to check spots that don't exist. So for a coordinate (0,0) that only has 3 adjacent spots, the program would only check spots (0,1),(1,1),(1,0) whereas a spot with  8 adjacent spots (5,3), it would only check spots (4,2),(4,3),(4,4),(5,2),(5,4),(6,2),(6,3),(6,4). Checking spots that don't exist causes a segmentation fault within my compiler. I'm unsure of how to write the loop to check adjacent spots of my vector within respect to its boundaries. Does anyone have any recommendations for how to write the loop?

Comment: I'd use two nested for loops, and inside the innermost loop I'd do an if check to see if the coords are in bounds, and if so proceed to check, otherwise skip.

Comment: This should all be encapsulated as a single class that holds the underlying data and knows its own height and width. When checking a cell for adjacent cells, you do explicit checks to see if the current checked position is 0, height-1 or width-1

Comment: Showing your current code that holds the data would help us better answer your direct question.

Comment: @Eljay thanks. your suggestion really helped :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a common practice for solving this. You precache every pair of neighboring offsets and then loop through those offsets while checking each one for out-of-bounds. Replace my array `int a[M][N]` with your vector in your code:

```
#include <iostream>

#define M 30
#define N 30

int main() {
    int nX[]{ -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1 };
    int nY[]{-1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1};

    int a[M][N];

    for (int y = 0; y < M; ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < N; ++x) {
            for (int n = 0; n < 8; ++n) {
                int yNeigh = y + nY[n];
                if (yNeigh < 0 || yNeigh > M) {
                    continue;
                }

                int xNeigh = x + nX[n];
                if (xNeigh < 0 || xNeigh > N) {
                    continue;
                }

                std::cout << a[yNeigh][xNeigh] << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I easy way to avoid segmentation fault in this case is create an array with dimensions *(n+1)X(m+1)*, where *n* is the number of rows and *m* is the number of columns. Put an special caracter in the row and column with indexes 0 and start to fill your matrix from row and column 1. To check the adjacencies instead of using an index *i* and *j*, use `i%n` and `j%n`so when you arrive in the last row or column instead of accesging the "invalid" positions that would cause segmentation fault you will access the row or column 0, that has a special character, so it will not make damage to your code.